Long term vs short term events
Present perfect tense for long term action
This page says we can use both present perfect simple and present perfect continuous tenses for long term event and only present perfect continuous tense for short term event.
https://www.wallstreetenglish.com/exercises/the-present-perfect-continuous#:~:text=When%20we%20talk%20about%20long,lived%20there%20for%2020%20years.
I am wondering how they define long term and short term.
I think in sentences 1-6 “have taught” should be replaced with “have been teaching” while sentence 7 can sound natural with both “have taught” and “have been teaching” because it’s a long term event. Am I right?
It seems two years is the boundary between long term and short term actions.

I have taught English for an hour.

I have taught English for a week.

I have taught English for a month.

I have taught English for six months.

I have taught English for a year.

I have taught English for one and a half years

I have taught English for two years



Long and short term are defined by context. Short term in a baby's recent life is different from short term in geology.

It would be an act of courtesy if you could occasionally vote on answers or accept one or two. People spend time answering your questions and I think there must been a few that actually help you. In nearly five years  your voting history is remarkable for its inactivity.

The present perfect tense has nothing to do with how long ago or the duration of time when something happens, or whether something is long term or short term.  There is no such boundary. Such understandings would depend on context. All of your sentences are grammatical.

I'd say #1 I have taught English for an hour doesn't imply I'm currently teaching English (or at least, was, until time of speaking or until very recently) anywhere near as strongly as I have been teaching English for an hour.  But if someone wants to wade through results for we've lived together for... and we've been living together for... I'd be interested to know if the average time differs.

I would say it’s two years. It applies to many verbs. “I have smoked for six months” is not the most natural. You would be more likely to use “I have been smoking for six months.” but two years is the time point when everything changes. “I have smoked for two years” is the same as “I have been smoking for two years.”

The OP has cast an upvote. Yay!

There is no absolute definition of "long term" versus "short term" in English grammar. There's nothing magic about 2 years. It depends on context. If you have a toothache for an hour, that could seem like a very long time. If a glacier has been melting for 100 years, that could be a short time. Even talking about the same subject the "boundary" could shift. Being a substitute teacher in one class for a year is a very long time. Being a senior professor at a well-established college for 10 years may not be very long.

It doesn’t actually answer the question. You will never say “I have taught English for one hour.” That’s definitely short-term. No doubt.

You might say, "I have taught English for one hour" if you mean how long your class today lasted. Or, I suppose, if you just started your teaching job today. Assuming you meant how long your class today lasted, that could be a long time if a typical class at your school is 45 minutes. Someone might mean, "wow, with all the questions after the lecture, that class dragged on for over an hour".
